Why aren't these calculations for area of a plane equal?
Very simple question and I know that I am doing something simple wrong.
Given the plane $3x + 2y + 4z = 9$, find the surface area of the plane in the first octant.
Using the integral for the surface area $\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\frac{9}{2}-\frac{3}{2}x}\sqrt{1+(-\frac{3}{4})^2+(-\frac{1}{2})^2}\text{dy}\text{dx}=\frac{27\sqrt{29}}{16}$, which is the correct answer.
Since plane is a triangle in the first octant, and since the sides of this triangle on the $x\text{-}z$ and $y\text{-}z$ axes form a right angle, I thought that I can just use the area of triangle to solve for the surface area.
$$\text{Area} =\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt{(\frac{9}{4})^2+(\frac{9}{2})^2}\cdot\sqrt{(\frac{9}{4})^2+3^2}= \text{INCORRECT}$$
However, this returns the incorrect answer. Can someone explain what is wrong with the second approach? Is it not a right triangle in the first octant? I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking. Thank you!

The vertices of the triangle are at $(3, 0, 0)$, $(0, 9/2, 0)$, and $(0,0,9/4)$. The edges with $(0,0,9/4)$ as a vertex are vectors with direction $(3,0,-9/4)$ and $(0, 9/2, -9/4)$, whose dot product is nonzero, so they are not perpendicular.

But aren't two vectors that are in two different planes (in this case, the xz and yz planes), perpendicular? Also I'm not the one who downvoted you.

Consider the vectors $(1, 0, 100)$ and $(0, 1, 100)$. They are in the $xz$ and $yz$ planes, but are almost parallel. @TreeGuy

Ah I see. I guess I don't have very good intuition for this.

@TreeGuy Also, note that if your original argument worked, you would also be able to argue that the other two angles of the triangle were right angles as well, which can't be possible.

yeah I see that now
